# openCV NDK (/javaCV) vs FastCV Vs android Vision for face processing

Tags: opencv, android-ndk, computer-vision, android-vision, fastcv

I am trying to process faces in images on a device/tablet. I have used opencv (NDK) a while ago. I see that there are couple of other options available to process faces. Just wondering how opencv, android-vision api and FastCV would compare specifically for processing faces;

Found couple of similar posts here but they did not answer all my questions.

[Android API face detection vs. OpenCV/JavaCV face detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27683958/android-api-face-detection-vs-opencv-javacv-face-detection)

[Android Computer Vision JavaCv OpenCV Fastv comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673099/android-computer-vision-javacv-opencv-fastv-comparison)

My questions:
1) How does android face api (face detection and landmark extraction) compare to opencv (javaCV or opencv NDK) (accuracy Vs speed) 
2) Is FastCV better for this? I presume it comes with license restrictions.
3) Does the android api work for all android devices?

I found couple of ports for open-source CV libraries (other than opencv) that are commonly used for pc based CV applications but these are not optimized for the devices, I found them very slow when used as is.
thanks!

Comment: What did you end up using? I am using android vision api but if detector's All classification is enabled it slows down performance.

Comment: I had to take the traditional path (javacv) for non-technical reasons. I was more interested in the key points in the vision api as I could use them for alignment and registration. I know this depends on the phone we use for testing but how much time does it usually take for face detection and the fiducial poiny extraction? I think the relative timing info should be comparable across different phones.